# tailwind css Classes are not included if they are type in a string vue

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

i'm use TailwindCss with vue

if i write component he has a prop like color:

```html
<script setup>
defineProps({
    color: String // give me like: green
})
</script>

<div class="`bg-${color}-500`"> </div>
```

But when I see the result the color does not appear because Tailwind did not understand that this color was used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding on to Markiesch, Tailwind suggests not writing classes this way as they are not recognised by the purger on build, which means the class as you wrote it will most likely not work in production.

[Tailwind docs state](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The class is not applying because the browser doesnt understand the syntax `bg-${color}-500`. Use the build-in Vue feature `v-bind:class=""` or using the shorthand `:` to make this work

```
<div :class="`bg-${color}-500`"> </div>
```